# channelRead not being called in Swift-NIO Datagram's ChannelInboundHandler

Tags: swift, vapor, datagram, swift-nio

I am trying to capture a UDP video stream within a (fresh) vapor application running in Xcode. The data is being streamed by ffmpeg and I can successfully view the stream on the target machine using VLC, which is also the one running the vapor application, using `udp://0.0.0.0:5000`. I have used various bits of Apple documentation to get to the code below. When I run it, I get these lines of output on the console log, but I wonder if they are not relevant:

```
2021-07-07 17:59:27.102681+0100 Run[10550:2494617] [si_destination_compare] send failed: Invalid argument
2021-07-07 17:59:27.104056+0100 Run[10550:2494617] [si_destination_compare] send failed: Undefined error: 0
```

In configure.swift:

`try setupClient()`

This is the client code:

```swift
final class FrameHandler : ChannelInboundHandler {
    typealias InboundIn = AddressedEnvelope<ByteBuffer>
    typealias OutboundOut = AddressedEnvelope<ByteBuffer>

    func channelRead(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, data: NIOAny) {
        // minimal for question
    }
    
    func errorCaught(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, error: Error) {
        // minimal for question
    }
}

func setupClient() throws {
    let group = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 1)
    let bootstrap = DatagramBootstrap(group: group)
        .channelOption(ChannelOptions.socketOption(.so_reuseaddr), value: 1)
        .channelInitializer { channel in
            channel.pipeline.addHandler(FrameHandler())
    }
    defer {
        try! group.syncShutdownGracefully()
    }

    let channel = try bootstrap.bind(host: "0.0.0.0", port: 5000).wait()
    try channel.closeFuture.wait()
}
```

The problem is that although `channelRegistered` and `channelActive` are called, followed by a never-ending stream of `readComplete`, the important one `channelRead` never gets called - neither does `errorCaught`. If I comment out the call to setupClient then there is no network activity, however, if it runs then Xcode's network monitor shows activity consistent with the levels in ffmpeg. So, I believe the connection is being set up.

I wonder if the problem is in the way I am setting the handler up? All the examples use echo or reflecting chat examples, so the inbound handler is set up in the closure of the data-writing function using the context rather than adding it in the initialiser (although, the outbound handler is set up in this way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Vapor 4 which is based on SwiftNIO 2. And in NIO 2, the `ChannelHandlerContext` variable is called `context` and not `ctx`. So if you just rename all your `ctx` to `context`, I'd assume it'll work.